# Mismatched types `[int]` vs `[int, .. 0]`

Tags: rust

I'm facing an issue in Rust I have not yet found an answer to:

```
mismatched types: expected `[int]`, found `[int, .. 0]`
```

My code looks like:

```
struct Foo {
  bar: [int]
}
```

And I'm trying to set it to an empty slice:

```
Foo {
  bar: []
};
```

The types should be right, but maybe the size isn't.

Any ideas? I suspect it's something little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until dynamically sized types are implemented properly, you can't use bare `[T]` as a struct field, and even when they will be implemented, you probably wouldn't *want* it.

It seems you want to store an array into a struct, right? There are two ways to do it in Rust, depending on who owns the array content.

When the struct instance itself should own the data, then the simplest way is to use `Vec<T>`:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<int>
}
```

You create its instance like this:

```
Foo {
    bar: vec![1, 2, 3]
}
```

When the struct instance should only borrow the data, you should use a slice, `&[T]`:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    bar: &'a [int]   // or &'a mut [int] if you need to modify contents
}
```

Then you create it like this:

```
let data: Vec<int> = ...;  // obtained from somewhere
// slices can only be taken from existing data, e.g. Vec<T>, or be &'static
Foo {
    bar: data.as_slice()   // or as_mut_slice() for &mut [int]
}
```

I really recommend you reading excellent [official guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide.html) which explains difference between owned vectors and slices and many more things.